# PHP date from today to 4 months

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Does anyone know why this keeps on showing the date 01-05-70?

```
$effectiveDate = strtotime("+4 months", strtotime($effectiveDate)); // returns timestamp
echo date('d-m-y',$effectiveDate); // formatted version
```

I want it to print today's date + 4 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `$effectiveDate` contains an invalid date. So `strtotime()` returns the unix epoch Jan 1, 1970.

But you shouldn't need that variable at all if all you want is the date four months from now.

```
echo date('d-m-y',strtotime('+4 months'));
```

Comment: Fantastic John, thanks so much. Do you know how I express the year as 2016 as opposed to 16?

Comment: Use a capital Y : echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime('+4 months'));

Comment: Hi John, that is fantastic, thanks. Who'd have thunk, a capital Y?

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = date('d-m-y');
$monthsFour = date('d-m-y',strtotime("+4 months"));
echo $today;
echo "<br>";
echo $monthsFour;
```

Your question in comment : `Do you know how I express the year as 2016 as opposed to 16?` 
Replace `y` in date function with capital `Y`

**Edited:**

```
$today = date('d-m-Y');
$monthsFour = date('d-m-Y',strtotime("+4 months"));
echo $today;
echo "<br>";
echo $monthsFour;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know why this keeps on showing the date 01-05-70?

`$effectiveDate` may contain an invalid timestamp, I prefer using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, i.e.:

```
$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '09-08-2016');
$d1->add(new DateInterval('P4M'));
echo $d1->format('d-m-Y');
```

---

[Demo](http://ideone.com/nha6bD)